# FilterSelectMultiple in Django form not saving

Tags: python, html, django, forms, widget

I'm trying to create a user permission field in my webpage using django form to work exactly like in admin page using `FilterSelectMultiple`. Currently it populating the data correctly and the select and deselect button is working, but I unable to save the form, whenever I hit save, the page refresh and all the user are deselect again.

The

```
user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(),
                                                  widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('User', is_stacked=False))
```

is not working.

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated thank you

Below is my code :

HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css" />

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id=setting_form" name="setting_form" onsubmit="updateDiv()">{% csrf_token %}  

<!--USER-->
   <div class="field">
       <label>User permissions:</label>
       <div class="related-widget-wrapper">
       <select name="user_permissions" id="id_user_permissions" multiple="multiple" class="selectfilter" data-field-name="user permissions" data-is-stacked="0">
           <option value={{ form.user }}></option>
       </select>
   </div>

   <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
       <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="/admin/jsi18n"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
```

View.py

```
def project_setting(request):
    form = EditProjectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=selected_project, prefix='settings')
    if form.is_valid():
        inst = form.save(commit=False)
        inst.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/projects/{}/setting'.format(project_id))

    context = {

        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/projects/setting.html', context=context)
```

Form.py :

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class EditProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
        user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(),
                                              widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('User', is_stacked=False))
```

Model.py :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, blank=True)
```

**EDIT :**

After inspecting the page source, my form is declaring like this

```
<select name="user_permissions" id="id_user_permissions" multiple="multiple" class="selectfilter" data-field-name="user permissions" data-is-stacked="0">
      <option value=<select name="settings-user" id="id_settings-user" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="3">User A</option>
      <option value="4">User B</option>
   </select></option>
</select>
```

Its declaring another `<select>` inside my `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that widget, but, it looks odd to render the user field into the option tag like that. I also don't see a closing form tag, or a submit button?

I would have thought it would go something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css" />

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id=setting_form" name="setting_form" onsubmit="updateDiv()">{% csrf_token %}  

<!--USER-->
   <div class="field">
       <label>User permissions:</label>
       <div class="related-widget-wrapper">
       {{form.user}}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
<script src="/admin/jsi18n"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
```

Comment: My apologies, I simplified my code and i forgot to add the submit button and the close tag, thank you for pointing it out, 

Yes, my original syntax was `{{form.user}}` but the field will displayed as standard `ManytoManyField`. I wanted it to display as a `FilteredSelectMultiple`

Comment: So then specifying `widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('User', is_stacked=False)` had no effect?

Comment: yes that is correct, the reason its displaying is because I recreate the select fields just like User permission from admin page and change the value, it should've work but it populating selected and deselect data properly in their respective field so now I'm just trying to figuring out how to save

Comment: Can you log out the request.POST data from the `project_setting` view